# How to type greater than or equal to symbols?

Tags: support, mathjax

What are the markups for such symbols?

Comment: `\geqslant` (and `¸leqslant`) for $\geqslant$ (and $\leqslant$). See [this post](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) for general information about MathJax commands.

Comment: or just `\ge` for $\ge$ and `\le` for $\le$

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use `$\ge$` or `$\geq$`  (to get $\geq$) or for a variant `$\geqslant$`
(to get $\geqslant$).

For less than or equal to replace the "g" by "l".

For the strict versions, $\gt$ and $\lt$,  you can use `$\gt$` and `$\lt$`, 
 or just the symbols `$>$` and `$<$`. The symbols did sometimes create issues but I think this is fixed by now.

For a general guide see [MathJax basic tutorial and quick reference](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)

Comment: Not completely fixed, unfortunately. When `$a<b$` is in a title, and another question is closed as a duplicate of it, the automatic comment has `$a&lt;b$` which doesn't render: $a&lt;b$. This isn't a reason to avoid strict inequality signs in titles as much as a reason to [finally fix this over-escaping bug](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/13319)...

Comment: Thanks, I was not aware of this. What I thought of was an issue that the post got completely cut off as something got misinterpreted.

Comment: That also happens, when new users post things like `a<b therefore -b>-a` without dollar signs: this renders as `a-a` on the site. Some such questions get closed as unclear, unless someone realizes what is going on and edits.